# how to show ListView in Dialog with multiple Checkbox

Tags: android

1. In Main activityi take one button and on button click I want to show data in list view with multiple checkbox in dialog with positive okay button.
2. when i click on button then dialog close and show selected data in Main Activity. again i click on button to open dialog then i want check again which are selected.

Comment: you can see this link to take suggestion.....http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html
and simply take the listview in the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Multiselect Dialog.

```
boolean[] spb = { false, false, false, false, false };

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final CharSequence[] items = { "one", "two",
                    "three", "four", "five" };
            final boolean[] temp = { false, false, false, false, false };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ViewAll.this);

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, spb,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                temp[which] = true;
                            } else {
                                temp[which] = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Submit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            spb = temp.clone();

                            // Do your stuff
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

**Note:** Length of `spb` and `temp` should be same as `items`.

Happy Coding..

Comment: your code is okay but when i open second time i see all are selected but without change i press button okay and 3rd time i open then its unchecked .